# Substituir include do php para javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou fazendo um site que eu sou obrigado a usar **HTML**, **CSS** e **JavaScript** no máximo. Só que muitas coisas que eu preciso do **PhP** eu não posso usar.
Sendo assim eu estive pesquisando por sinonimo de `include()` e encontrei o seguinte, que ajudou em partes:

```
        <select id="cidade" name="cidade">
            <option selected disabled>-- Selecione uma cidade --</option>
            <option value="atibaia">Atibaia - SP</option>
            <option value="bragancapta">Bragança Paulista - SP</option>
        </select>

<script>
document.getElementById("cidade").onchange=function() {
    document.getElementById("inserir").innerHTML = "<object type='text/html' data='cidades/" + this.value + "/index.html' width='100%'>";
}
</script>
<p id="inserir"></p>
```

Tá, mas qual é o problema? Ele cria uma barra de rolagem do lado. Eu sei como remover com **CSS**, mas o texto que foi inserido rola só dentro da área da `div` e eu queria que fizesse como se o texto inserido fizesse parte da página, como funciona no `include()` do **PhP**. A questão é, como fazer a mecânica do **JavaScript** nesse caso ficar igual ao do **PhP**?

Print para exemplificar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWzom.jpg

Comment: Aumento o tamanho do elemento com o atributo `height` (via CSS)

Comment: Isto acontece pq você está carregando no **p** como se fosse um html novo, por isso a barra, pq usou `object`?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr consegui mais ou menos no seu comentário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver com a ajuda do Valdeir Psr nos comentários. Ele deu uma sugestão certa da forma errada. Eu apenas adicionei isso no meu **CSS**:

```
object {
height: 100%;
}
```

E já respondendo o LeAndrade, usei `object` pois ele foi o que melhor me serviu nessa aplicação do meu código **HTML** e também todos os tutoriais e aplicações do mesmo jeito sugeria usar `object`. Posso até buscar uma tag mais otimizada posteriormente, mas isso me serviu por enquanto.